# Rails/ActiveRecord has_many through: association on unsaved objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Let's work with these classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_participations
    has_many :projects, through: :project_participations, inverse_of: :users
end

class ProjectParticipation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project

    enum role: { member: 0, manager: 1 }
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_participations
    has_many :users, through: :project_participations, inverse_of: :projects
end
```

A `user` can participate in many `projects` with a role as a `member` or a `manager`. The connecting model is called `ProjectParticipation`.

I now have a problem using the associations on unsaved objects. The following commands work like I think they should work:

```
# first example

u = User.new
p = Project.new

u.projects << p

u.projects
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Project id: nil>]>

u.project_participations
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: nil, role: nil>]>
```

So far so good - AR created the `ProjectParticipation` by itself and I can access the `projects` of a `user` with `u.projects`.

But it does not work if I create the `ProjectParticipation` by myself:

```
# second example

u = User.new
pp = ProjectParticipation.new
p = Project.new

pp.project = p # assign project to project_participation

u.project_participations << pp # assign project_participation to user

u.project_participations
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: nil, role: nil>]>

u.projects
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Why are the projects empty? I cannot access the projects by `u.projects` like before.

But if I go through the participations directly, the project shows up:

```
u.project_participations.map(&:project)
=> [#<Project id: nil>]
```

Shouldn't it work like the first example directly: `u.projects` returning me all projects not depending on whether I create the join object by myself or not? Or how can I make AR aware of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer**: No, second example won't work the way it worked in first example. You must use first example's way of creating intermediate associations directly with user and project objects.

**Long answer**:

Before we start, we should know how `has_many :through` is being handled in `ActiveRecord::Base`. So, let's start with [`has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1245-L1248) method which calls its association [builder here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb#L28-L42), at the end of method the returned [reflection](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L623) and then add reflection to a [hash](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L11) as a cache [with key-value pair here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L33-L35).

Now question is, how do these associations gets activated?!?!

It's because of [`association(name)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L150-L160) method. Which calls [`association_class`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L440-L445) method, which actually calls and return this constant: [`Associations::HasManyThroughAssociation`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L442), that makes [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L118) to autoload *active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb* and [instantiate its instance](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#L7-L12)  [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L155). This is where [owner and reflection](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb#L27) are saved when the association is being created and in the next reset method is being called which gets invoked in the subclass `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionAssociation` [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L64-L67).

Why this reset call was important? Because, it sets `@target` as an array. This `@target` is the array where all associated objects are stored when you make a query and then used as cache when you reuse it in your code instead of making a new query. That's why calling `user.projects`(where user and projects persists in db, i.e. calling: `user = User.find(1)` and then `user.projects`) will make a db query and calling it again won't.

So, when you make a [reader](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L29-L37) call on an association, e.g.: `user.projects`, it [invokes the collectionProxy](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L36), before populating the `@target` from [`load_target`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L373-L380).

This is barely scratching the surface. But, you get the idea how associations are being build using builders(which creates [different reflection](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L15-L31) based on the condition) and creates proxies for reading data in the target variable.

#### **tl;dr**

The difference between your first and second examples is the way their association builders are being invoked for creating associations' reflection[(based on macro)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L15-L31), proxy and target instance variables.

**First example:**

```
u = User.new
p = Project.new
u.projects << p

u.association(:projects)
#=> ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyThroughAssociation object
#=> @proxy = #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Project id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
#=> @target = [#<Project id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]

u.association(:project_participations)
#=> ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation object
#=> @proxy = #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: nil, role: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
#=> @target = [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: nil, role: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]

u.project_participations.first.association(:project)
#=> ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation object
#=> @target = #<Project id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

**Second example:**

```
u = User.new
pp = ProjectParticipation.new
p = Project.new

pp.project = p # assign project to project_participation

u.project_participations << pp # assign project_participation to user

u.association(:projects)
#=> ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyThroughAssociation object
#=> @proxy = nil
#=> @target = []

u.association(:project_participations)
#=> ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation object
#=> @proxy = #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: nil, role: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
#=> @target = [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: nil, role: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]

u.project_participations.first.association(:project)
#=> ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation object
#=> @target = #<Project id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

There's no proxy for `BelongsToAssociation`, it has just [target and owner](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/02d3a253610eaf9c80587913b366e3fa0f56b71f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb#L27).

However, if you are really inclined to make your second example work, you will just have to do this:

```
u.association(:projects).instance_variable_set('@target', [p])
```

And now:

```
u.projects
#=>  #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Project id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

In my opinion which is a very bad way of creating/saving associations. So, stick with the first example itself.

Comment: Thanks for the links into the source and the `.association` method. This gives an insight how associations work and was the most helpful answer.

Comment: How can I set the `role` of the association in the first example? So I want to add a user to the project with the role `member` or `manager` but still have the association work.

Comment: You can do: `user = User.new{ |u| u.role = Role.new(name: 'member') }` and then `p = Project.new`, `user.projects << p`.

Comment: I don't have a `Role` - the `role` is in the connecting table `project_participations` ( `enum role: { member: 0, manager: 1 }`, because a user can have different roles in different projects). So in general I want to set some attributes from the `project_participations` table when assigning a user to the project.

Comment: I see, I think it can't be done this way. You'll have to update project participation explicitly by calling `u.project_participations.first.role = 'manager'`.

Comment: So this means I cannot use it with one `update_attributes` call easily ... would you mind to look at my other question, which has something to do with this one in some way, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868641/update-attributes-on-has-many-through-associations-and-working-with-the-unsaved ? Maybe you have a better solution if you have some time.

Comment: u.association(:projects).instance_variable_set('@target',[p]) -- is this the only way to set association data via an :symbol that identifies a relation? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a rails structure thing at the level of the ruby data structures.
To simplify it lets put it this way.
First of all imagine User as a data structure contains:

1. project_participations Array
2. projects Array

And Project

1. users Array
2. project_participations Array

Now when you mark a relation to be **:through** another (user.projects through user.project_participations)

Rails implies that when you add a record to that first relation (user.projects) it will have to create another one in the second realation (user.project_participations) that is all the effect of the 'through' hook

So in this case,

```
user.projects << project
#will proc the 'through'
#user.project_participations << new_entry
```

Keep in mind that the project.users is still not updated because its a completely different data structure and you have no reference to it.

So lets take a look what will happen with the second example

```
u.project_participations << pp
#this has nothing hooked to it so it operates like a normal array
```

So In conclusion, this acts like a one way binding on a ruby data structure level and whenever you save and refresh your objects, this will behave the way you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**At the risk of some serious oversimplification let me try to explain what is going on**

What Most of the other answers are trying to tell you is that these objects have not been linked yet by active record until they are persisted in the DB. Consequently the association behavior that you are expecting is not fully wired up.

Notice that this line from your first example

```
 u.project_participations
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: nil, role: nil>]>
```

Is identical to the result from your second example

```
u.project_participations
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil,   project_id: nil, role: nil>]>
```

This statement from your analysis of what you think rails is doing is inaccurate:

> **So far so good - AR created the ProjectParticipation by itself and I**
>   **can access the projects of a user with u.projects.**

AR record has not created the ProjectParticipation.  You have declared this relationship in your model. AR is just returning proxy for the collection that it will have at some point in the future, which when populated assigned, etc, you will be be able to iterate over and query its members etc.

The reason that this works:

```
u.projects << p

u.projects
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Project id: nil>]>
```

But this doesn't

```
pp.project = p # assign project to project_participation

u.project_participations << pp # assign project_participation to user

u.project_participations
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: nil, project_id: nil, role: nil>]>

u.projects
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Is that in the first case you are just adding objects to an array that your user instance has direct access to. In the second example the has_many_through relationship reflects a relationship that happens at the database level. In the second example in order for the your projects to be accessible through your user, AR has to actually run a query that joins the tables and returns the data you are looking for.  Since none of these objects is persisted yet that database query can't happen yet so all you get back are the proxies.

The last bit of code is misleading because it is not actually doing what you think.

```
u.project_participations.map(&:project)
=> [#<Project id: nil>]
```

In this case you have a user which is directly holding an array of ProjectParticipations one of which is directly holding a project so it works. It is not actually using the has_many_through mechanism in they way you think.

Again this is a bit of an oversimplification but that is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Associations are defined on **database level** and make use of database table's *primary key* (and in `polymorphic` cases, *class name*). In case of `has_many :through` the lookup on association (say, `User`'s `Project`s) is:

1. Fetch all `User`-`Project` pairs, whose `user_id` is a certain value (primary key of an existing `User` in the database)
2. Fetch all `project_id` (primary keys of projects) from these pairs
3. Fetch all `Project`s by resulting keys

Of course, these are simple terms, in database terms it's much shorter and uses more complicated abstractions, such as an `inner join`, but the essence is the same.

When you create a new object via `new`, it is not yet saved in the database, and therefore has **no primary key** (it's `nil`). That said, if the object is not in a database yet, you have no way of referencing it from any ActiveRecord's association.

**Side note:**
There is a possibility, however, that a newly created (and not saved yet) object will act as if something is associated with it: it might show entries belonging to `NULL`. This usually means you have an error in your database schema that allows such things to happen, but hypothetically, one could design his database to make use of this.

Comment: In both examples in my question nothing has a primary key because everything is unsaved, but still the first one works and the second not.

Comment: Unsaved entries have their own temporary collections for each association. But they are designed for defining associations directly, as instructions of what to do on save. `has_many :through` assumes an **implicit** connection: to fetch entries defined indirectly, it would have to loop through the `through` model and fetch all `Project`s referenced in them. Instead, it only accesses the temporary association's collection that contains only items **explicitly** added to that model.

Comment: This might be considered a bug from a certain standpoint. But the truth is, this still allows you build data for most (if not all) practical cases.