# Update attributes on has_many through associations and working with the unsaved object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, has-many-through

This has something to do with my [last quesion about unsaved objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651811/rails-activerecord-has-many-through-association-on-unsaved-objects), but now it is more about a specific problem how to use rails.

The models I have are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_participations
    has_many :projects, through: :project_participations, inverse_of: :users
end

class ProjectParticipation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project

    enum role: { member: 0, manager: 1 }
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_participations
    has_many :users, through: :project_participations, inverse_of: :projects

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_participations
end
```

With this models, when I create a new project I can do it by a form (`fields_for` etc) and then I can call `update_attributes` in the controller. So if I have users in the database already, I can do this:

```
u = Users.create # save one user in database (so we have at least one saved user)
p = Project.new

# add the user to the project as a manager
# the attributes could come from a form with `.fields_for :project_participations`
p.update_attributes(project_participations_attributes: [{user_id: u.id, role: 1}])
=> true
```

This works fine until I want to do something with the `users` of a project. For example I want add a validations that there must be at least one `user` for a project:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    validates :users, presence: true # there must be at least one user in a project
    ...
end
```

This now gives:

```
u = Users.create
p = Project.new

p.update_attributes(project_participations_attributes: [{user_id: u.id, role: 1}])
=> false

p.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:... @base=#<Project id: nil>, @messages={:users=>["can't be blank"]}>

p.users
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

p.project_participations
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectParticipation id: nil, user_id: 1, project_id: nil>]>
```

So on unsaved `projects` the `.users` is empty. This already bugs me (see [my last quesion about unsaved objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651811/rails-activerecord-has-many-through-association-on-unsaved-objects)). But in this case I can of course now work around this by doing `validates :project_participations, presence: true` instead of `validates :users, presence: true` and it should mean the same.

But this would mean I should never use the `.users` method (in any helper, model, view, ...) unless I am totally sure that I work with a saved object. Which in fact renders the `.users` method unusable (like it does with the validation of user`s presence).

If I call `update_attributes` like this, the validations works and it saves:

```
p.update_attributes(users: [u])
```

With this it creates the `project_participation` by itself so `p.users` works as expected. But here I cannot set any data like `role` for `project_participation` of that user.

So my questions are: Can I make the `.users` method work whether or not the object is saved (I think not)? But then, how can I add users to a unsaved project as a manager/member and work with the unsaved project?

I hope my problem is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you question, and you're correct in assuming that you cannot use the `.users` method whether or not the `project` model is saved.  The reason for this is that in defining an association in `Project` (ie. `has_many :users, through: :project_participations, inverse_of: :projects`) you're telling rails to read the `users` attribute out of the database via the `project_participations` join table and when you haven't saved the project you have nothing to read out of the database.

In order to add a `User` to your project in a particular role you will need to create a new `ProjectParticipation` model which you will then associate to your project.  If you then remove the `users` association and write your own `users` method you should be able to access your collection of users regardless of whether or not the project has been saved.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_participations

    ...

    def users
        project_participations.collect { |pp| pp.user }
    end
end
```

Then something like:

```
u = Users.create
p = Project.new

pp = ProjectParticipation.new({user: u, project: p, role: 1})
p.project_participations << pp
p.users
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: This works for now but I think this is not the cleanest solution. (For example because it is slow to collect every user in a separate query etc). I'll try to work with this and see how far I come and then maybe accept the answer / add new comments.

Comment: Please do add comments if you find a better way.